# Can't resolve activity for result

Tags: android, android-activity, android-imagebutton

I'm creating a dynamic button to capture photo from android. The dynamic button is located in a different class from main activity. I got `Can't resolve` error on my `startActivityForResult` here is [my code](http://pastebin.com/e2W0Etrq)

I'll appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: how do you call startActivityForResult ?

Comment: have you see my code from the attached link?

Comment: My bad, I didn't see this part in the code.

Comment: Would you add error log.

Comment: I think you missing requestCode(int) in this line : activity.startActivityForResult(cameraIntent); replace with this : activity.startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,CAMERA_REQUEST);

Comment: @FengDai no error log, because I can't compile the code because of that error

Comment: @HareshChhelana would you like to post your comment as answer, because I want to vote your suggestion.

Comment: So your code doesn't compile ? Didn't your IDE help you figure out the call to startActivityForResult takes 2 arguments ?

Comment: onActivityResult() is a method of an Activity and you are trying to override in view class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

Keep mind custom class can not override onActivityResult() only Activity extended class override onActivityResult() so you have to override onActivityResult() in your Actitvity and given call back to your custom class like below

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private JsonGuiImageView jsonGuiImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        jsonGuiImageView = new JsonGuiImageView(this);
        setContentView(jsonGuiImageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void  onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if(requestCode == jsonGuiImageView.CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            jsonGuiImageView.setPhoto();
        }
    }
}

public class JsonGuiImageView extends LinearLayout {
    private ImageView imageView;
    private ImageButton button;
    private Intent cameraIntent;
    private Bitmap photo;
    private Context context;
    public static int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1777;
    private String imagePath;

    public JsonGuiImageView(Context context){
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.setOrientation(VERTICAL);
        this.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        this.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        button = new ImageButton(this.context);
        button.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(60, 60));
        button.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        button.setMaxHeight(60);
        button.setMinimumHeight(60);
        button.setMaxWidth(60);
        button.setMinimumWidth(60);
        button.setOnClickListener(AddImage);
        this.addView(button);
    }

    public JsonGuiImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet){
        super(context, attributeSet);
    }

    OnClickListener AddImage = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "image.jpg");
            imagePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
            cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(file));
            if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(((Activity)context).getPackageManager()) != null) {
                ((Activity)context).startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        }
    };

    public void setPhoto(){
        photo = decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(imagePath, 480, 640);
        imageView = new ImageView(getContext());
        imageView.setMaxHeight(60);
        imageView.setMinimumHeight(60);
        imageView.setMaxWidth(60);
        imageView.setMinimumWidth(60);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        this.addView(imageView);
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
    {
        Bitmap decode, rotatedBitmap = null;

        //First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize, Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        int inSampleSize = 8;

        if (height > reqHeight)
        {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
        }
        int expectedWidth = width / inSampleSize;

        if (expectedWidth > reqWidth)
        {
            //if(Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth) > inSampleSize) // If bigger SampSize..
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
        }

        options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inPurgeable = true;
        options.inInputShareable = true;
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

        try{
            ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(path);
            int orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            int rotation = 0;
            switch (orientation){
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90 :
                    rotation = 90;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180 :
                    rotation = 180;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270 :
                    rotation = 270;
                    break;
                default: break;
            }

            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(rotation);

            decode = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
            rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(decode, 0, 0, decode.getWidth(), decode.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return rotatedBitmap;
    }
}
```